# What is the mechanism of docker to create a container to drop access to other host file data?

Tags: docker

I want to know the mechanism of how does docker creates a container on the host. As for how to isolate the container's storage.We know that provisioning a file system for a container is a two-step procedure:1)populate a sub-directory of the host's file system with data and code.2)make the subdirectory the root of the new container.We can use AUFS or overlayfs to do the first step.I always thought that docker use `chroot` to do the second step. But I recently read a blog that said docker use mount namespace by the call like `unshare`.

I am confused that how can only use mount namespace to drop access to other host file data?
When I used the command unshare, it surely created a new mount namespace for the process. And it copied identical host's mount points. But it can still read other host file data..I want to know  that did I misunderstand the blog's saying..

Comment: Please add the link to the mentioned blog.

Comment: Actually, it's a paper published by ATC'18 named SOCK:Rapid Task Provisioning with Serverless-Optimized Containers. In section 2.1 Container Storage it said that `The older chroot operation simply turns a subdirectory of the original root file system into the new root file system.A newer mount-namespace abstraction...`.And in section 4.1 lean containers it said that `We use the faster and simpler chroot operation since it is not necessary to selectively expose other host mounts within the container for serverless applications`.

Comment: So I am confused that is mount namespace an alternative way? Docker didn't use chroot to drop access to other host file data？If mount namespace can do this alone, how?

Comment: the paper's link is right here: https://www.usenix.org/conference/atc18/presentation/oakes , you can download the pdf below.